# Consumir webservice de consultas de endereços de uma determinada cidade

Tags: java, web-service, aplicação-web, play-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web preciso alimentar todos com os endereços das ruas e dos bairros da cidade onde moro, e apos realizar um determinado serviço pelo usuário, vincula-lo a um endereço. Para não fazer o cadastro manualmente de todos os nomes de ruas e bairros, até porque não é viável, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece um web service para esta minha aplicação.

Obs:.Estou desenvolvendo usando o PlayFramework 1.4 e na linguagem java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que trabalho com API e tenho que usar consultas de endereços, eu utilizo esta api https://viacep.com.br. Agora dependendo do que vc quer fazer, vc pode fazer a consultar do endereço na hora usando o CEP/Endereço ou pode fazer um script que faça a busca de todos os endereços da sua cidade com base nos CEPs e salvar no banco de dados.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br essa API do Google retorna os endereços que voce quer, basta enviar latitude e longitude.